# Rounding Microseconds to Milliseconds MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, math, milliseconds

How is the best way to round microseconds to milliseconds in mysql?

For example, in a datetime(6) column, how do we round

2016-12-01 12:30:01.122456 to 2016-12-01 12:30:01.122

and

2016-12-01 12:30:01.122501 to 2016-12-01 12:30:01.123

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(TO_SECONDS(dt) -
                     TO_SECONDS('1970-01-01 00:00:00') +
                     (ROUND(MICROSECOND(dt) / 1000, 0) / 1000)) AS new_dt
FROM yourTable
```

Here `dt` is your `datetime` column.  For the sake of explanation, I will break down the above query using `2016-12-01 12:30:01.122456` as an example.

```
MICROSECOND(dt) = 122456
ROUND(MICROSECOND(dt) / 1000, 0) = 122
```

then

```
(ROUND(MICROSECOND(dt) / 1000, 0) / 1000)) = 0.122
```

So `0.122` is the number of fractional seconds in your `datetime`, which doesn't contain any precision in the microsecond range after rounding.

```
TO_SECONDS(dt) = # seconds EXCLUDING the fractional part
```

Finally, we take the number of seconds in `dt` since year 0 and subtract off the number of seconds from year 0 to the start of the epoch.  This leaves us with number of seconds in `dt` since the start of the epoch.  Then, we add the number of seconds excluding the fractional part to `0.122` to obtain the total number of seconds of the desired new `datetime`.  At last, we use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert this number of seconds back to a bona fide `datetime`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work FROM_UNIXTIME results in a null value.  The TO_SECONDS works, but FROM_UNIXTIME sets that to NULL.. Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(TO_SECONDS('2015-12-11 12:31:04.080000') +
                     (ROUND(MICROSECOND('2015-12-11 12:31:04.080000') / 1000, 0) / 1000)) AS new_dt  results in a null value, but the following :   select TO_SECONDS('2015-12-11 12:31:04.080000') +
                     (ROUND(MICROSECOND('2015-12-11 12:31:04.080000') / 1000, 0) / 1000) returns a value..

Comment: What does `MICROSECOND('2015-12-11 12:31:04.080000')` give you?

Comment: 80000 is the result of MICROSECOND('2015-12-11 12:31:04.080000')   Thx